# Laravel + docker-compose + external db, very low performance

Tags: laravel, performance, amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-rds

There is a project consisting of three containers:

- web - nginx
- app - php (laravel 5.4)
- db - mysql (5.7)

from considerations of stability, I plan to move the database to aws.
The test showed that the loading time of the application during the transfer to the aws is increased by several times. Seems like each request to the db, is a connection to the database.

The api-call does something like this:

```
$mycustomer = $customer->find($id);
$mycustomer = $this->getCustomerFooData($mycustomer);
$mycustomer = $this->getCustomerBarData($mycustomer);
...
...
return $mycustomer;
```

takes in:

- container 1200 milliseconds;
- aws 64000 milliseconds

(microtime(true))

Docker-compose.yml with DB Container:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  web:
    container_name: my_web
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8040:80"
    links:
      - app
    networks:
      - portrouter_default
  app:
    container_name: my_app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    links:
      - database
    networks:
      - portrouter_default
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
  database:
    container_name: my_db
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - portrouter_default
    environment:
        - „MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password"
        - „MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname"
    ports:
        - "33063:3306"
networks:
  portrouter_default:
    external: true
```

Docker-compose.yml without DB Container:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  web:
    container_name: my_web
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8040:80"
    links:
      - app
    networks:
      - portrouter_default
  app:
    container_name: my_app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - portrouter_default
networks:
  portrouter_default:
    external: true
```

.env db-container:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33063
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

.env aws:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=xxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=33063
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal that it will be slower from your localhost to AWS than from your localhost to your localhost. If you want to verify real performance you should deploy your app to AWS connect it to RDS and then verify real performance.

Comment: ok, thanks! I will test it tomorrow. but what if I do not want to deploy the app on aws? such other Root-Server and Database by AWS. Is there no solution for this case?